# Is there a way to index CHM files in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, chm

Can anyone please suggest me a method by which a chm file can be indexed in such as **pdfbox** for pdf.

Comment: Apache Tika is more common to use with Lucene, I just didn't know about their support for CHM. So, accept deathy's answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have also other document formats which you need to index, you might find a better and more general solution in [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)

They just added a CHM Parser recently (for reference: [Support of CHM Format](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-245)) and it will be in the next version.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about [Microsoft Compiled HTML Help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) files, you can just extract text from them with [JChm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jchm/) and then index it in a normal way.

Comment: Be careful. There might be a binary and a textual (.xml stored as .hhk) index, and they might not contain the same things.

Comment: I used ChmParser amd used its retrieve file and have put some workaround. It seems to work well , and the .hhc issue is resolved . Thnx again